# Is This Derivation of Velocity as a Function of the Force of Air Resistance Correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics

I have seen the derivation of velocity with air resistance done using the equation, $F_d=-bv$ where velocity can be expressed as
$$v(t)=v_0e^{-\frac{b}{m}t}.$$
However, I'm looking for a corresponding equation of velocity using the more accurate:
$$F_d=\frac{1}{2}C_D\rho Av^2$$
The following was my attempt at deriving such an equation:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{F_d}{m}=\frac{C_D\rho Av^2}{2m}$$
$$\int_{v_0}^v\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{dv}{dt}dt=\int_{t_0}^t\frac{C_D\rho A}{2m}dt$$
$$-\frac{1}{v}\bigg|_{v_0}^v=\frac{C_D\rho A}{2m}t\bigg|_{t_0}^t$$
$$-\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{v_0}=\frac{C_D\rho A}{2m}t$$
$$\frac{1}{v}=-\frac{C_D\rho A}{2m}t+\frac{1}{v_0}$$
$$v(t)=\bigg(-\frac{C_D\rho A}{2m}t+\frac{1}{v_0}\bigg)^{-1}$$
I have tried verifying this equation with a few examples but none of the answers I've solved seemed plausible which leads me to believe I made an error somewhere within the derivation. The purpose of this derivation is to find a solution that does not involve the damping coefficient. Can someone please clarify the correct equation of velocity if one exists?

Comment: The force should be negative if the object is moving in the positive direction, no?

Comment: You solved the equation you posed correctly, but it is probably not the equation you wanted to solve. For example, you are currently in big trouble when $t=\frac{2m}{v_0C_D\rho A}$. But, as mentioned in the answer, you can get yourself our of trouble by reversing one sign: $v(t) = {\left(\frac{C_D\rho A}{2m}t+\frac{1}{v_0}\right)}^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you simply have a sign error.

$v$ should be decreasing because of the force, and decreases faster the greater $v$ is.  So $\frac{dv}{dt}$ is negative, and your equation is:

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{F_d}{m}=-\frac{C_D\rho Av^2}{2m} $$

Which gives your final $v(t)$ the form:

$$v(t)=\frac {1}{A+Bt}$$

which is a function that has a positive value at $t=0$, and decreases to zero as $t$ increases, as you would expect.